# Using Chinese characters in PDF::API2::Simple

Tags: perl, pdf, fonts, chinese-locale

I'm writing PDFs from a Perl script using PDF::API2::Simple.

UIuse UTF-8 for my text and it works great until I have Chinese characters in the text, which only show up as boxes.

```
PDF::API2::addFontDirs('/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/');
my $TimesNewRoman = $pdf->pdf->ttfont('Times_New_Roman.ttf', -encode=>'utf-8');
$pdf->add_font('Times New Roman', $TimesNewRoman, 14);
$pdf->set_font('Times New Roman', 14);
$pdf->text($whateverText);
```

Is there a way to have PDF::API2::Simple fall back to another font if the current font can't show all the characters ?

Strangely LibreOffice seems to be able to display the same text string in Times New Roman...

Comment: Can you include example text please?

Comment: i am no expert on PDF::API2, but if i inspect `/Library/Fonts/Times New Roman.ttf`, then there is no chinees in it at all. You probably need to choose from any of the cjkfonts like `my $cjk = $pdf->pdf->cjkfont('KozMin-Bold')`and use that one instead

Comment: @vanHoesel: Thanks, that works, but even in the Chinese CJK fonts some Chinese characters are missing that I have in my data and they also don't seem to have all European umlauts. I wish there was a way to generate PDFs without having to know which characters there are in the text and it would fall back onto other fonts.